# How to create a new DataFrame from a Dataframe excluding rows based on count of occurunces in a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
     foo  bar
0  Alice   42
1  Alice   44
2    Bob   22
```

and I am trying to get a new data frame excluding the last row because `Bob` occurs only once in column `foo`

```
     foo  bar
0  Alice   42
1  Alice   44
```

Here is the code that I use to create the data frame seen above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": ["Alice", "Alice", "Bob"],
        "bar": [42, 44, 22]
    }
)
```

and my approach on this requirement (which does not work..)

```
col_foo_gt_1 = df["foo"].value_counts() > 1
print(col_foo_gt_1["Alice"])  # Prints true
print(col_foo_gt_1["Bob"])  # Prints false

df_bob_removed = pd.DataFrame(
    df[col_foo_gt_1[df["foo"]]]
)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another solution using `.transform`:

```
df_bob_removed = df.loc[
    df.groupby('foo')['foo'].transform('count') > 1, 
]

     foo  bar
0  Alice   42
1  Alice   44
```

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**

Use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby('foo').filter(lambda x: len(x) >1)

     foo  bar
0  Alice   42
1  Alice   44
```

**Method 2**

You could set the index to `foo` and then use `loc`:

```
df.set_index('foo').loc[(df.foo.value_counts() >1)]

       bar
foo       
Alice   42
Alice   44
```

If you wanted to reset the index after that:

```
df.set_index('foo').loc[(df.foo.value_counts() >1)].reset_index()
     foo  bar
0  Alice   42
1  Alice   44
```